# Dojo Table Container cols based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I am using **Dojo UI** for the layout of a form application. I am using **Dojo Table Container** to hold form elements. Based on the screen size i would like to set the columns (data-dojo-props="cols:) of the Table Container to either 1, 2 or 3 however i am not able to set a dynamic value for the Table Container Columns. Under is a sample of the container with elements.

How can i set the value of `data-dojo-props= cols:` at runtime ?

I know it can be done with java script by detecting the screen size and using `dijit.byId().set("attribute", value)` however this deals with design and layout and i prefer if it is handled by css. So i need a css solution.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer"
     data-dojo-props="cols:2,customClass:'employee_labels', labelWidth:210"
     id="EmployeeContainer">

 <input type="text" id= "fname" />
 <input type="text" id= "lname" />
 <input type="text" id= "age" />
 <input type="text" id= "phone" />


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create the layout container dynamically.

```
<div id="tablecontainer"></div>
<script>
require( ["dojo/dom", "dojox/layoutTableContainer"], function ( dom, tablecontainer ) {
   var noOfCol = 3;
   var tblCont = new tablecontainer({
       cols:noOfCol ,
       customClass:'employee_labels', 
       labelWidth:210
   }, dom.byId("tablecontainer"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Cant it be done from css using @media and setting the cols value ?